# Feature for favoriting answers?

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I stumbled on a question today that seemed like an ok question, good enough for an upvote but one of the answers snagged my attention so much that I wanted to favorite it.  Favorites for me are like browser bookmarks, that i want to revisit to utilize every bit of info I can get out of it, time and time again.  I realize that if I were to favorite the question, it would take me there still but I'd rather favorite the answer, so that the user who posted it would know they made a real impression on someone.  Does that sound silly?

Comment: FWIW, I'd like this too.

Comment: I was going to write a [site blog](http://blog.photo.stackexchnage.com) highlighting some of my favorite answers on the site (maybe as a regular feature). I never got around to it and got busy with other stuff, but maybe you'd like to do it instead? I don't think that replaces this feature request, but it's a parallel approach.

Comment: It's very tempting!  I don't think I could commit to the time right now, but I'd love to maybe sometime in 4 or 5 months or so.  That would be cool, actually.

Answer (score 4):

Under each question and answer there is a "share" link. Click that to get a permalink that will jump you directly to that question or answer. You could then just bookmark the permalink.

Comment: Well that's exactly what I'm talking about, thanks!!!

Comment: Still, it would be lovely to have the feature strictly for making good answerers happier to help out.

Answer (score -1):

Why not favourite the question instead? You never know when a better answer might come along, too.

Comment: As I stated above, I'd rather favorite the answerer, as it is their thoughts I loved, not the question.  This way, the user who gave the 'favorited' answer gets an ego boost, which is, in all seriousness, a good way to reinforce user activity on the site.  Users that feel they are really contributing tend to be more active here, wouldn't you agree?